# Fluctuating Learning Curve

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN model, here is the code.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(300, 300,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(300, 300)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
])
```

I am using Adam with 0.00003 learning rate, and training on 100 epochs.

However, The 10 epochs the validation starts to fluctuate  between 0.16 and 0.22. ( I can't use early stopping because each time i retry the training the minimum is reached after a random number of epochs ).

Is this learning Curve normal ? what can i do to improve it ?

[image: curve]

Comment: from my experience, this is absolutely normal, no need to worry. You can try pushing your training a little longer (around `500` epochs) and lowering your learning rate (divide it by `3` and then `10`) to see if you get better results.

Comment: You can also try to add BatchNorms. i don't know what problem you are trying tosolve, but with Conv2D, it's usually a good idea

Comment: thank you for your answer i will try this.

Comment: I tried with 300 epochs the validation did'nt change i can see that i am overfitting, as only the test decrease to 0.

I tried both Dropout and BatchNormalization but the error increased it become between 0.18-0.28

Comment: OK, then I guess you an still try to lower your learning rate, but once again, it is perfectly normal  to have this kind of oscillations (but they can be a symptom of a too high learning rate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is normal, no need to get worried, but for the future, I would suggest applying smoothing to the graphs, this will help you understand a lot better what is going on. For example, look at this graph I captured from tensorboard

[image]

The transparent graph is with the initial values, and the darker graph is a smoothened graph. the smoothened graph shows that the model is minimizing the loss, very haphazardly and slowly, but it is minimizing nonetheless.

Sometimes viewing a smoothened out graph can help better identify the training of the models.

Comment: This is really helpfull, but in my situation even after 300 epochs, the validation error is constant.

Can you advice me what to do to decrease it ?

Comment: Get more data, augment it, or try other architectures, this will help a lot

Comment: Agreed, it is pretty obvious that your model is overfitting to your data, hence the training loss is decreasing but validation loss is flatlining. Generally, if your model overfits to small amounts of data, then it means it has the ability to generalize for that problem, the issue is most definitely the amount of data, I can see you are using 300x300 images to train a binary classifier, how many images are there as a whole? Is the data biased? Meaning do you have an equal distribution of both the classes? These answers will help us better understand the problem

Comment: I am using only 250 images, that is all the data that i could get. I am using Data augmentation too. 
I know it is a very small amount of data, but is this the best i could get ?

Comment: I don't have an equal distribution too, ( it is a regression problem btw, i have values between 2.5 and 3.5

Comment: The dataset is indeed quite small, apologies I didn't the activation function, I just saw 1 node in the last layer and assumed it was a binary classifier.  With regression, especially large amounts of data is a necessity, in terms of loss it looks like your validation data is also being fit well. I think rather than worrying about non-decreasing loss, it would be better to check MSE on your validation data.

Comment: also, a suggestion, if your values are between 2.5 and 3.5, it's better to subtract 2.5 from these, so that your network predicts between 0-1, you could always add 2.5 at the time of sampling and get the same answer. In terms of learning, I think it would be a bit easier for the network. Could be that it doesn't affect it at all. But it's better to be safe